# Trouble outputting full list of numbers using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml, sequential-number

the following is code to create a sequential list of numbers from 1 to 10.  I'd like to take this list and output in the div "pagination" using innerHTML.  However, when I execute the script, the only thing that is outputted is the number 10.  When I overwrite the page using document.write instead, it outputs the whole list.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

```
function generateNumbers() {
    var numbers = new Array();

    // start generating numbers
    for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i+= 1) {
        numbers.push( i );
    }

    // print numbers out.
    for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("pagination").innerHTML = numbers[i] + "<br>";
    }
}
```

and in the HTML:

```
<div id="pagination"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you override `innerHTML` in every step.
Try:

```
document.getElementById("pagination").innerHTML += numbers[i] + "<br>";
```

Or better:

```
// no for loop
document.getElementById("pagination").innerHTML = numbers.join("<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("pagination").innerHTML = numbers[i] + "<br>";
}
```

This replaces the `innerHTML` every single time through the loop, so you only see the last iteration.

Try making that `=` a `+=`.

Or even better, build it up in a string and set the `innerHTML` just once with that final string.  This will be faster since it only has to parse the string as HTML once instead of 100 times.

Comment: how would you build it up in a string and then set innerHTML to that?  Would it just be setting numbers[i] + "<br>" as a variable?

Comment: like: `var html = '';` then in the loop: `html += numbers[i] + '<br>';`.  Although the `join` method above is cleaner all around.